# How can I connect vertices of a 3d plot in python with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My code is as follows:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig3 = plt.figure()
ax = fig3.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection='3d')

X, Y, Z = [2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2.5],[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5],[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
ax.plot(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```

and produces this plot:
[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDAEA.png)

However, I would like to connect the vertices, and am aiming for this:
[Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF5rX.png)

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "connect the vertices"? The "goal" image you posted doesn't connect all of them either, so you must have some further criterion which ones to connect.

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/Oqlzncg.png) is what it would look like if you were to connect *all* vertices.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is to connect the vertices in that manner. In order to mimic the design in the second image, which is that of a basic house.

Comment: If you just want to manually produce that picture without any algorithmic cleverness, you can just keep calling `ax.plot` with the coordinates of each pair of vertices that should be connected. Perhaps make a list of coordinate tuples `((x_start, x_end), (y_start, y_end), (z_start, z_end))` and then loop over them.

Comment: I am a but unsure what you mean. How would I go about implementing that?

Comment: Get the start and end points for every line you need to add in your figure; write each one as a nested tuple like I did above; collect all these points in a list; and then loop over that list and call `ax.plot` with the x, y, z tuples as the arguments. If you're happy with a hand-crafted solution like this (and not an algorithmic one like @JohanC suggested below), I'll put an outline of it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the volume to be drawn is convex, and you're happy with triangles, you can calculate and draw the convex hull:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import numpy as np

fig3 = plt.figure()
ax = fig3.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

X, Y, Z = [2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2.5], [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
X = np.array(X) # convert to numpy arrays
Y = np.array(Y)
Z = np.array(Z)
ax.plot(X, Y, Z, "ro")

hull = ConvexHull(np.array([X, Y, Z]).T)

# each simplex is a the triangle of the convex hull
for s in hull.simplices:
    s = np.append(s, s[0])  # append the first coordinate at the end to create a closed polygon
    ax.plot(X[s], Y[s], Z[s], "b-")
plt.show()
```

[image: drawing the 3D convex hull]